# TableLayoutPanel update lag

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, tablelayoutpanel

I have a WinForms app which is updating a TableLayoutPanel from a BackgroundWorker. Depending whether a device input is On (1) or off (0) the colour and some text is changed accordingly.

```cs
try
{
    //Define a new TLP to hold the search tablelayoutpanel. 
    //search for the iterated card number.
    //get the status label using GetControl from Position.
    TableLayoutPanel TLP = new TableLayoutPanel();
    string IO_Card_Name = "ED527_" + i.ToString();
    TLP = TLP_IO_Info.Controls.Find(IO_Card_Name, true).FirstOrDefault() as TableLayoutPanel;
    try { lbl = TLP.GetControlFromPosition(4, 0) as Label; } catch { lbl = null; };
    //if card is found (because input is active, colour the TLP (card) according to its state.
    if (TLP != null && lbl != null && INPUTS[i - 1] == 1)
    {

        TLP.BackColor = Color.Green;

        foreach (Label l in TLP.Controls)
        {
            l.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        lbl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lbl.Text = "ON"; });
    }
    else if (TLP != null && lbl != null && INPUTS[i - 1] == 0)
    {
        TLP.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (Label l in TLP.Controls)
        {
            l.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        lbl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lbl.Text = "OFF"; });
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
};
```

`TLP` holds 5 labels in it. The update shows some noticeable lag when the line updates. Is there a way I can carry out something akin to `SuspendLayout()` / `ResumeLayout` on the main UI thread?

****EDIT to show the before and after - the IOLabel column updates slightly before the Status column.

[image: Table Layout Panel]

Comment: I'm sure you don't mean this `TableLayoutPanel TLP = new TableLayoutPanel();`  Among other things.,,,,

Comment: why you set text in Invoke method but color without Invoke? I think all changes to GUI must be inside Invoke. All this code only change labels, put it all inside one Invoke (it will be called in main thread). Another part of BackgroundWorker function that fills INPUTS let work in own thread. If scan device very frequent there posible time lag in unpdating UI. Put small Thread.Sleep() after one scan loop or scan in timer.

Comment: @JQSOFT i'll preface on the fact i have had no formal training as a computer scientist so i am sure there are a number of faux pas in my code.

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov - I did think that but it doesn't throw an except with the colour for some reason... I will pop it all into an invoke. This code block is called from a backgroundworker with a `Thread.Sleep(100)` pause.

Comment: Sorry buddy, just meant to pass a hint to be checked. Doing mistakes is an essential part of the job. No errors/mistakes/exceptions means you don't code much. Now if you kindly elaborate a little bit more to clarify things like what do you mean by `Device` on/off part? and what is `INPUTS` array? so we can get better understanding for the problem.

Comment: No worries - I prefer to clarify that I am very much in the domain of 'I don't know what I don't' with coding. I appreciate all the help i can get :)
The `Device` is a physical device called a [Brainbox](https://uk.farnell.com/brainboxes/ed-516/ethernet-16-di-67ac3667/dp/2911473?gclid=CjwKCAjw1v_0BRAkEiwALFkj5svP0AQ_oOJqSrTFBguR1G7SxUXwYILvNj-KzgOH9qpdj8R_8lNeIxoC6T4QAvD_BwE&mckv=sSMRLZ7cf_dc|pcrid|417160447804|kword|+brainboxes%20+ed-516|match|b|plid||slid||product||pgrid|92933587414|ptaid|kwd-675687906952|&CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SKU-MDC).

Comment: `INPUTS` is the list of the inputs as described in the [documentation](http://www.brainboxes.com/files/pages/support/faqs/sample_code/Brainboxes.IO.Documentation/html/P_Brainboxes_IO_EDDevice_Inputs.htm)  `INPUTS` is returned from a method in a separate class (which handles the Brainbox control).
I am polling the brainbox every 250milliseconds from the BackgroundWorker. if an input switches on, I am attempting to have the UI update to show the user an input has triggered. this update of the `TableLayoutPanel' lags(you can see the label on the left update slightly before the one on the right)

Comment: @JQSOFT - i have added a picture to my main post for some further clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds you have a nested design. Each row is 5 Labels are hosted by different TableLayoutPanels and the `TLP_IO_Info` which is a TableLayoutPanel hosts the other TableLayoutPanels. In the `DoWork` event of the BackgroundWorker you have a `for..loop`  to change the `Backcolor` of the inner controls according to the current *state* of the devices which you read it from the `INPUT` int array. Please correct me.

I'd like to suggest this:

```cs
foreach (var tlp in TLP_IO_Info.Controls.OfType<TableLayoutPanel>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("ED527_")))
{
    if (tlp.GetControlFromPosition(4, 0) is Label lbl)
    {
        var state = // get the state of the current device from INPUT array
        var stateColor = state == 1 ? Color.Green : Color.White;
        var stateText = state == 1 ? "ON" : "OFF";
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            tlp.BackColor = stateColor;
            tlp.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(l => l.BackColor = stateColor);
            lbl.Text = stateText;
        }));                        
    }
}
```

Or this to eliminate the redundant code:

```cs
var stateColors = new[] { Color.White, Color.Green };
var stateTexts = new[] { "OFF", "ON" };

foreach (var tlp in TLP_IO_Info.Controls.OfType<TableLayoutPanel>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("ED527_")))
{
    if (tlp.GetControlFromPosition(4, 0) is Label lbl)
    {
        var state = // get the state of the current device from INPUT array
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            tlp.BackColor = stateColors[state];
            tlp.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList()
            .ForEach(l => l.BackColor = stateColors[state]);
            lbl.Text = stateTexts[state];
        }));
    }
}
```

Note that, I've removed the expensive `try..catch` blocks since this code won't throw any exceptions.

As for the `INPUT` array, I suggest that you replace it with a `Dictionary<string, int>` to store the current state of each device since (according to the link you've provided) each device has a unique `IOLineNumber` so you can easily set/get the current state of each one.

<sup>⍰ Maybe there is already something like this in the library?</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this! This has made the update much smoother. I have to modify it slightly to fit (there is also an `OUTPUTS` array) but this is really elegant and gives me some interesting syntax to research. I've never used syntax like: `var stateColor = state == 1 ? Color.Green : Color.White;` before
thanks again! :)

Comment: if i could ask an additional question I am also trying to have the Color of the `tlp` be user defined. i.e. `var stateColor = state == 1 ? Color.**User Defined Colour** : Color.White;`  How can I imbue this information into my `tlp` or `lbl`?

Comment: Most welcome buddy and thank you. As for the Color issue, you need to store that color somehow in your app to set/get it anytime anywhere. Use for that the [application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-new-setting-at-design-time), add new setting entry of `Color` type like MyColor, then you can access it like `Properties.Settings.Default.MyColor` to set/get it. To use it in our snippet: `var stateColor = state == 1 ? Properties.Settings.Default.MyColor : Color.White;`